# Date picker should be enabled only for 2 year and 6 months in future date in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The date in date picker should  be enabled only future 2 year and 6 month from today date,after that date should be disabled.(it should not accept current or past date)

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepickerOne').datepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                endDate: '+0d',
                autoclose: true
            }).on("change", function () {
                $("#studentDetailsForm").bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'certification_date');
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var expireDate = new Date();
expireDate.setFullYear(expireDate.getFullYear() + 2);
expireDate.setMonth(expireDate.getMonth() + 6)
expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() -1);
$( "#expires" ).datepicker({
  maxDate: expireDate,
});
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input name="expires" type="text" id="expires" readonly/>
```

I used custom function to determine the max date in this way you can specific your own logic to determine which are valid dates.

Answer (score 3):

As **Surjit SD** said use minDate and maxDate to set it to no value before today and max 30 months in the future. Code should be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepickerOne').datepicker({
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        minDate: -0,
        maxDate: "+30M"
        autoclose: true
    }).on("change", function () {
        $("#studentDetailsForm").bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'certification_date');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery datepicker widget then it has options to restrict dates.

Restrict the range of selectable dates with the minDate and maxDate options.

Refer Jquery https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Example

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery UI Datepicker:

Take a look at: 
 [jQuery UI mindate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)
and [jQuery UI maxdate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)

Answer (score 1):

Well you are using **[bootstrap-datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)**

So you used right option `endDate` but for 2 years and 6 months you need this value:

```
endDate: '+910d'
```

**In your code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datepickerOne').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    endDate: '+910d',
    autoclose: true
  }).on("change", function() {
    $("#studentDetailsForm").bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'certification_date');
  })
});
```

<sub>*Note: 910 days mean 2 years and 6 months*</sub>

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datepickerOne').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    endDate: '+910d',
    autoclose: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<input type="text" class="datepickerOne">
```